# Installing Ubuntu along with Windows 8.1

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm using Windows 8.1 and also want to install Ubuntu as dual-boot?.

Should I install Windows 8.1 on a separate partition and Ubuntu on another partition? Is there any problem like file distortion in case of installing both operating systems on a single partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). The answer by Luis Alvarado has the answers to your questions about partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Wubi, you need to install Ubuntu in a separate partition. Alas Wubi is deprecated and unsupported by Canonical and *doesn't work at all in UEFI environments*. Please perform a regular installation and choose "alongside Windows".

While there is no practical risk, that Ubuntu damages your Windows installation or data on Windows partitions, both the manual or the automated re-partitioning, that occur before or during the first installation of Ubuntu on a system with pre-installed Windows, may fail or be interrupted (e. g. by a power failure), in which case your data would likely be lost. **It is important that you back up your data. Data without a backup is by definition unimportant.** And that's not just for Ubuntu or its installation procedure.

Relevant resources:

- [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](/q/221835)
- [Install Alongside Windows or Something Else - Which should I use?](/q/223341/175814)